# How to parse nested FireBase data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve values from firebase and use in my project but its not happening. Data structure is as follows:
[image]

I have keys "user" and "1","2",....which contain values. The numbers are incremental, as it is in my screenshot, I have "1", if i push 3 items at one go, the keys will be:

-FirebaseId 1

"user"..

"1"..

"2"...

"3"..

But how do i retrieve the values?

```js
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("sales");
        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                Log.d("on_child_added1", String.valueOf(map.get("user")));
                Log.d("on_child_added2", String.valueOf(map.get("1")));
                Log.d("on_child_added3", String.valueOf(map.get("amount")));
                Log.d("on_child_added4", String.valueOf(map.get("city")));

            }
          ...........
```

Comment: you're trying to get every element from the top level, consider trying things like: sales[0]>1>amount, sales[0]>1>user>city

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do

Comment: but you aren't, you're just doing map.get(), map is the top level here, so you need to get the objects at each level and then use your key to access the value. map.get("sales") should give you the whole sales object. salesmap.get(-that sales ref unless sales was an array-) will give you the object that has user and 1...2...3 in it. So reference these objects then query them appropriately. I'm not sure if you can or what, but JSON would be much easier to work with here IMO

Comment: Wait, I can use Json? Please continue

Comment: That's good you should then.. or use POJO->JSON serialization and just treat it as an object

Comment: @Saik Caskey do you have an example I can follow?

Comment: this is fairly fundamental.. I think you should google "android parse json" or "android deserialize pojo" or for a case more related to you "firebase datasnapshot parsing" or "firebase datasnapshot pojo serialization". If you haven't seen this before, do some tutorials. Stack overflow has a lot of questions like this that you could consult